# issue adding csv file attachment to email in Batch job

Tags: apex, email, batch, csv, singleemailmessage

In a batch file we are updating records, and for each one we are creating a record which is sent in an email when the batch completes.

It all works swimmingly except that the csv file is sent as an HTML file with the name `UpdatedEntityrecords.csv.html`

This is very strange, as nowhere in my code do I append the word *.html* to the filename...

here is the code where the work is done:

```
    string sEmailBody='Please see the attached file for details of the ' + RecordNo + ' records updated.';
    if (iErrorsCount > 0){
        sEmailBody+='\n\nThere were '+iErrorsCount +' errors during the batch';        
    }       

    sEmailBody += '\n\nThis email was sent by the batch job \'BATCH_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status\' ';

    string csvHeader='Id, Name, Cif ID, TimeStamp, LastModifiedDate, Errors\n';
    csvData = csvHeader + csvData;

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

    system.debug('Send email');

    if (RecordNo>0){
        //Create csv attachment
        system.debug('add csv file attachment');     
        blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(csvData); //updatedEntities
        string csvname= 'UpdatedEntityrecords.csv';
        csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
        csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);            
    }

    //Create Email      
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {'theTeam@ourLittleBank.co.uk'}; 
    String[] ccAddresses = new list<string> {'aPerson@ourLittleBank.co.uk'}; 

    email.setSenderDisplayName('Entity records Equation status Batch job');
    email.setSubject('Entity records Equation status updated');       

    email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
    email.setCcAddresses( ccAddresses );        

    if (RecordNo>0){
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});    
        email.setPlainTextBody(sEmailBody);
    }else email.setPlainTextBody('No records were updated by the batch process');        

    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    system.debug('email sent');
```

so is there something else I need to do in order to have the attachment put on as a csv file, instead of a ...csv.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be because you are not setting `contentType` of attachment. And set filename as well by `setFileName(String fileName)` method.

```
if (RecordNo>0)
{
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvBlob }); 
        email.setContentType('text/csv');   
        email.setPlainTextBody(sEmailBody);
}
```

Also,`csvBlob` needs to be passed instead of `csvAttc`.